# Magento 2 - Manipulate custom address attribute 'is_required' value before checkout

Tags: magento, magento2

How can I **programmatically change** "is_required" value of **custom address attribute before checkout**. Currently attribute value of "is_required" is set to false because its not mandatory field on checkout when creating/editing address but I would like to change that value depending on some statement. Thats why I dont want to change it in admin because there is specific case when it needs to be set as mandatory field on checkout.

How can I do that in code?

Here is what I tried and it is not working.

Plugin:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Address">
        <plugin name="customer_adjust_address_attributes"
                type="CustomModule\Customer\Plugin\Model\Address"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

After method from plugin:

```
    public function afterGetAttributes(DefaultAddress $subject, $result)
    {
        $customerType = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getCustomerType();

        if ($customerType == PhoenixCustomerHelper::CUSTOMER_TYPE_BUSINESS) {
            foreach ($result as &$attribute) {
                if ($attribute->getName() == 'gui_number') {
                    $attribute->setIsRequired('1');
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

To conclude, method is executed as I checked it with xdebug and attribute is_required value is set from '0' to '1' but field still remains optional on address form on checkout so nothing changed.

Thanks, Denis